# UICollectionView swift 4: Add different datas in each section

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to add different datas in each sections. 
Instead of using scrollview, I want to use UICollectionView.

How to achieve this?

Output:
[image: This will be the output]

Comment: https://ibb.co/hgNBy0

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to what you have.

1st. You don't create different sections because you can simply create rows with different cell design.

so in this, you row data structure will be an enum

```
enum Rows{
    case headerRow(your associated data)
    case descriptionRow(your associated data)
    case FormRow(your associated data)
}

var data : [Rows] = []

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let currentData = data[indexPath.row]
        switch currentData {
        case .headerRow(let associatedData):
            // configure data with cell
            // return headerRow Cell
        case .descriptionRow(let associatedData):
            // same as above
        case .FormRow(let associatedData):
            // same as above
        }
    }

}
```

2nd approach will be using sections. But I only recommend using it if you have different rows in a section. In this case, it is more or less the same, but you define your sections to be enum and extend from there.